# calling pthread_cancel() in loop shows increase MEM usage

Tags: c, linux, memory-leaks, pthreads

I am testing `pthread_cancel()` functionality with my test code in C. This is not the exact code I am using but a simplified form for explanation.

```
int main(argc, char *argvp[])
{
    while(1) {
        start_thread();
        sleep(5);
        end_thread();
    }
}

void my_thread(void *arg) 
{
     printf("in my thread\n");
     pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, NULL);
     return 0;
}

void start_thread()
{
    pthread_create(&my_id, NULL, &my_thread, NULL);
}

void end_thread()
{
    pthread_cancel(my_id);
}
```

If I do `ps aux` on my machine, I see that for my above process the `RSS` section is always increasing.But if I replace `pthread_cancel()` with `pthread_join()`, RSS for my process doesn't increase.

I am not allocating any resource in my thread so it seems like `pthread_cancel()` is not cleaning up some pthread related stuff behind the scenes?

I know `pthread_cancel()` is killing the thread because my thread count stays stable at 2 (checked with top ... main process + my_thread).

I looked over the pthread_cleanup_pop/push funcs but they look like they are used to clean user allocated memory.

Do I need to use them every time with `pthread_cancel()`?

Edit: RSS increases in the amount of 4kBytes every once loop.

Comment: If you're not joining dead threads, then, yeah, memory usage is going to keep increasing because the resources associated with that thread are't getting freed... (`pthread_cancel()` is rarely a good idea; notify your threads that they need to stop so they can do so gracefully and then join them.)

Comment: I have a blocking curl call in the thread. If I want to terminate the thread,I cannot call join on the thread while it is blocked. I thought aync pthread_cancel would do the job.

Comment: Don't make multiple threads for blocking functions.

Comment: That would cause even more memory leaks due to curl stuff not getting cleaned up.... I suppose the next question is why are you using blocking curl requests if they need to be interrupted. Use its non-blocking incremental API.

Comment: Unfortunately I am stuck with the current implementation using blocking curl instead of the multi_curl. Curl handle cleanup is called  after the pthread_cancel().

Comment: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-multi.html

Comment: If you know the underlying socket being used by the curl connection, just close it.  That will break the blocking read immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling pthread_detach() after pthread_cancel() will free the resources which were held/used by pthread "itself.

Of-course the user must make sure on his own that his/her own allocated resources inside the now cancelled thread are also free'ed up.

Comment: Is there a callback for pthread_cancel to pass a void* argument in case any cleanup needs to be done?

Comment: If you want to free resources that were allocated inside the thread by the user, then you can use the cleanup push/pop handlers. They will be called automatically once your thread receives its cancellation notification. 

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cleanup_push.3.html